# How can i show more than one UialertController

Tags: swift, view, uialertview, uialertcontroller

Hi i'm making a register tableview and i have to show the total of mistakes that the person did filling it in uialertcontroller.

```
for var i = 0; i < subJson.count; i++ {
                let messag = ("\(key): \(subJson[i])")
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error al registrarse", message: messag, preferredStyle: .Alert)
                let acceptAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Aceptar", style: .Default , handler: nil)
                alert.addAction(acceptAction)
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
```

I have this and the error is it :

Attempt to present UIAlertController  on  which is already presenting (null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible now because de uialertview it's deprecate in xcode version 7.0.1.

So try to rebuild your application logic

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, you can only show one alert at a time.

Comment: Yeah i see, Thanks very much